Job Scheduler Implementation with monitoring the job Using cloud (Azure Web jobs) in Dotnet
I need idea or some suggestions on tool to create POC for our own job scheduler using following tech stack, which should replace the onpremimse AutoSys to cloud based solution.
Tech Stack:

Angular
C#, .NET 8.0
Azure PaaS (ex: Logic app, Function appm...)
PostgreSQL / SQL Server

POC scope:

Able to configure, monitor status of Jobs on UI
Able to schedule on-time and recurring jobs on UI
Able to trigger remote API on scheduled time for One-time job and recurring Job.

An on-premise AutoSys Enterprise Scheduler is already present in the existing landscape, but we won't be creating a complete AutoSys here. However, we can certainly implement it. Azure Cloud Services can help us implement a cost-effective solution that covers a few use cases in our portfolio.

yes, azure web jobs are available with no extra charges. where you can run your jobs in your desired fashion like ( continuos  or triggered).

here is api available for monitoring the azure webJobs  status continuously like cloud monix, kudu

We can try using Quartz.Net.
https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/
// you can have base properties
var properties = new NameValueCollection();

// and override values via builder
IScheduler scheduler = await SchedulerBuilder.Create(properties)
    // default max concurrency is 10
    .UseDefaultThreadPool(x => x.MaxConcurrency = 5)
    // this is the default
    // .WithMisfireThreshold(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
    .UsePersistentStore(x =>
    {
        // force job data map values to be considered as strings
        // prevents nasty surprises if object is accidentally serialized and then
        // serialization format breaks, defaults to false
        x.UseProperties = true;
        x.UseClustering();
        // there are other SQL providers supported too
        x.UseSqlServer("my connection string");
        // this requires Quartz.Serialization.SystemTextJson NuGet package
        x.UseSystemTextJsonSerializer();
    })
    // job initialization plugin handles our xml reading, without it defaults are used
    // requires Quartz.Plugins NuGet package
    .UseXmlSchedulingConfiguration(x =>
    {
        x.Files = new[] { "~/quartz_jobs.xml" };
        // this is the default
        x.FailOnFileNotFound = true;
        // this is not the default
        x.FailOnSchedulingError = true;
    })
    .BuildScheduler();

await scheduler.Start();

